# How to protect a Route using multiple define Gates? (Laravel)

Tags: laravel

I want to allow multiple gates on some of my endpoints and cannot seem to get it to work. this can easily be done using `@canany([])` on a blade file.

I need help, Please.

AuthServiceProvider.php

```
public function boot()
{
    $this->registerPolicies();
 
    Gate::define('update-post', function (User $user, Post $post) {
        return $user->id === $post->user_id;
    });
    Gate::define('store-post', function (User $user, Post $post) {
        return $user->id === $post->user_id;
    });
}
```

I am looking to add the gates on multiple route such as this below and it is failing as ode error. Looking so something that can work on this level.

web.php

```
 Route::get('/', function () {
        return view('welcome');
    })->middleware('can:['update-post', 'store-post']');
```

similar to what i am using on the blade file

```
 @canany(['update-post', 'store-post'])
```

Comment: Read the official [document](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/authorization#via-middleware) first before posting a question.

Comment: Is there any practical use case for this? Your example seems to imply that you need a user to be able to either store OR update a post meaning there are users who are able to update posts but are not able to store them (and vice-versa). It's more common to require users to be able to do both instead of any of them

Comment: Thank you @apokryfos same way i used the canany on the blade file, i want to apply it to the routes so to prevent guessing of the route. I am currently rethinking my process and working on setting up a gates that defines together update-post and store-post. Until i find a better response, lemme hack at this process.

Comment: I don't think this is possible with the built-in middleware. You may need to rethink your approach on this one or write a custom middleware that can handle this

Answer (score 0):

This is how it worked for me

```
 Route::get('/', function () {
        return view('welcome');
    })->middleware('can:update-post,can:store-post');
```